# My own class and context from widget

Tags: android, class, widget

Hy guys, i have a question for android developers...

I have a class named proKlasa()

```
public class proKlasa() 
{
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public void sendSMS(Context ctx, String number, String message, String notification_text) 
    {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, notification_text, System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, null, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, null, null, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null); 
    }
}
```

This class above I use for sending sms, and creating a notification, also I have an activity

```
public class Status extends Activity 
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        proKlasa pk = new proKlasa();
        pk.sendSMS(getApplicationContext(), "1234", "pozz", "notification text");
    }
}
```

When I start my application it automatically send a message and this work great. But when I want to do this in my widget, I have problem (NullPointerException). I think it's because the getApplicationContext(); but i dont now how to fix it. My widget loks like this down

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        proKlasa pk = new proKlasa();
        pk.sendSMS(context, "1234", "pozz", "notification text");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

And no, it is not because the remoteViews or appWidgetManager, this is only a example. I have a fully working widget, but when i put this code (pk.sendSMS...) it stops, anyone know where the problem might be?

EDIT: Problem solved, i had to put this

```
proKlasa pk = new proKlasa();
pk.sendSMS(context, "1234", "pozz", "notification text");
```

in onReceive, and in onUpdate put some setOnClickPendingIntent that will trigger te onReceive method, don't know why this works so, and don't in onUpdate, but it's ok for me :)

Comment: Come on guys, any one?, i need this...